# Name of specific solvable Lie Algebra of dimension 4

Tags: lie-algebras

I have a Lie algebra comprised of the generators $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$ for which the only non-zero commutators are

$$ [e_4,e_2]=-i e_3 $$
$$ [e_4,e_3]= i e_2 $$

(Excuse the physicist notation, for mathematicians the generators are actually ${ie_1,ie_2,ie_3,ie_4}$). Clearly, this is a solvable Lie Algebra ($[e_3,e_2]=0$).

My question is: Is there a simple way to refer to it without declaring its commutators? Like we can refer to $su(2)$ instead of writing out all of $su(2)$'s generators. I'd like to be able to do that for this algebra. If there's not a way to do this, I'd like to know that instead.

Comment: What is the field? $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb C$ or any? I can't understand completely your notation.

Comment: Sorry, $\mathbb R$ is implied in physics, so that we get unitary evolution. However, $\mathbb C$ would be just the complexification of the analogous "real" algebra, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the basis $$\{ f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4 \} = \{ e_1, i e_2 + e_3, e_2 + i e_3, e_4 \}$$ since all basis commutators are zero except for $$[f_4,f_2]=f_2 \quad [f_4,f_3]=-f_3$$

As emiliocba mentioned, the algebra is the direct product of a trivial one-dimensional algebra generated by $e_1=f_1$, and a three dimensional algebra generated by the other basis vectors.

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bianchi_classification) this three dimensional algebra is the Lie algebra of type Type VI<sub>0</sub>, the Lie algebra of the group of isometries of Minkowski space.

Answer (score 2):

Firt at all, your algebra $\mathfrak g$ can be written as 
$$
\mathfrak g=\mathfrak h\times \mathbb R,
$$
where $\mathbb R$ is the generated space by $e_1$ and $\mathfrak h=\langle e_2,e_3,e_4\rangle$.

Now, $\mathfrak h$ is one of the infinite solvable Lie algebras of dimension three. Look at Exercice 2 of Chapter I of [Knapp's book](http://books.google.com.ar/books?id=U573NrppkA8C&lpg=PP1&hl=es&pg=PA118#v=onepage&q&f=false). I don't know if these algebras have a name.